# How can I add a link to shared folders on Sharepoint for my colleagues?

Tags: sharepoint, directory, hyperlink, shared

I created my first Sharepoint page.  I added links to my coworkers files that they've shared with me.  However, I cannot find a way to add a link to folders they've shared with me.  Is this possible?

I can copy the link to their folder but it won't let me insert it to Sharepoint.

Comment: Can you describe it in more detail? Doesn't clicking share directly at the folder level meet your needs?